# detect CoreData unique constraint violation

Tags: core-data

I have a simple CoreData data model with:
name
timestamp
ident
where ident is a unique constraint.

With the following example code I try to insert a duplicate on the one hand and to make a duplicate out of an existing object on the other hand.
As expected, an exception is thrown.

```
struct CV:View {
  @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var moc
  @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [])
  
  private var persons: FetchedResults<PersonCD>
  
  var body: some View {
    VStack{
      Button("add Person A"){addPerson(id: "A")}
      Button("set first Person A"){persons[0].ident = "A"}
      Button("save Context"){saveContext()}
    }
  }
  
  private func saveContext(){
    do {
      try moc.save()
    } catch {
      let nsError = error as NSError
      print(type(of: error))
      print("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
      print("d:\(nsError.domain)")
      print("c: \(nsError.code)")
      print("ue: \(nsError.underlyingErrors)")
      print("cn \(nsError.className)")
      print("ds \(nsError.description)")
    }
  }
  
  private func addPerson(id:String) {
    let newPerson = PersonCD(context: moc)
    newPerson.timestamp = Date()
    newPerson.ident=id
  }
}
```

Two questions about this:

- What is the easiest way to distinguish the exception from other possible exceptions and react to it (I can only see an NSError)?
- Is it possible to get the information about which objects are in conflict, which is available in the description, as a reference to the duplicate objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This only causes an exception if you haven't set up a merge policy on your managed object context. The merge policy tells the context what to do if a conflict happens. If you don't set one up, the default policy is to throw an error.

Core Data has several built-in merge policies you can use, and most people find that one of these does the job they need. You would choose a merge policy with a line of code like

```
moc.mergePolicy = NSMergePolicy.mergeByPropertyObjectTrump
```

The built in policies are `mergeByPropertyObjectTrump`, `mergeByPropertyStoreTrump`, `rollback`, and `overwrite` (and of course `error`, which is what you have now). You can read about them in [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmergepolicy/).

If you want to handle it yourself, by getting details about the conflict, you can write your own merge policy and use that. To do that you'd create a subclass of `NSMergePolicy` like this:

```
class MyMergePolicy: NSMergePolicy {
    override func resolve(constraintConflicts list: [NSConstraintConflict]) throws {
        print("Constraint conflict list: \(list)")
    }
}
```

Then tell the context to use it with a line like this:

```
moc.mergePolicy = MyMergePolicy(merge: .errorMergePolicyType)
```

(You have to use one of the built-in merge policies here, you can't just use `()` to initialize it).

Now when a conflict happens, your custom merge policy will be called with an array of `NSConstraintConflict` objects. Those will [tell you all about the conflict](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsconstraintconflict/) with details of the constraint that was violated and what values were used and on what objects.

Comment: thx @Tom Harrington ! if there are multiple independent conflicts, is the policy called for each conflict?

Comment: As I understand it, it will be called once for each conflicting object even if that. Object has multiple conflicts. That’s why `NSConstraintConflict` has properties for a single conflicting object but for an array of conflicts.

Comment: I read, that using ** unique constraint** in combination with CloudKit ist not allowed. Is that true? Is there an other approach for this situation?

Comment: I don't know, sorry

Comment: Yes, this is true, see [this answer](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/656380) of an Apple Frameworks Engineer.